# Convert an InternetExplorer.Application object to HtmlAgilitypack element

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to open a web page which takes some time to load and then read data from the HTML. I used this :

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.Navigate("Web page which takes some time to load")

        Timer1.Interval = 5000 '5s
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub
```

As I was not able to read easily the HTML, I found some code on the web and I added this to convert to HtmlAgilityPack

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Doc.LoadHtml(ie.document)
    End Sub
```

But unfortunately, I get the error : the conversion from HTMLDocumentClass to String is not possible.

I tried to use "ieDoc As HtmlDocument" instead of "ie As Object" but with no succes. I tried a lot of examples that I found on the web but I was not able to fix this.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried loading it directly from the website instead of going via InternetExplorer.Application? [Load Html From Web](https://html-agility-pack.net/from-web)

Comment: ...or maybe using a WebBrowser class (not Control, just the class object), if the page needs to be rendered. Or WebView2.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Yes I have tried loading it directly and the web page is not completely rendered. I was not able to set the 25s timer so it loads the webpage with the initializing message.

Comment: @Jimi I tried WebView with no succes but WebView2 did it ! Thank you !